# Is there anything wrong with this unusual NSMutableArray setter?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties

This behaves to an outside observer mostly like `@property (copy)`, except it has the very nice property of automatically performing any side effects that may exist in `remove<Key>AtIndexes:` and `insert<Key>:atIndexes:`. If I'm going to have such side effects, this seems really handy (DRY!)--is there anything wrong with this strange-looking accessor method?

```
- (void)setEdges:(NSArray *)newEdges
{
    if (newEdges != edges)
    {
        [self removeEdgesAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [edges count])]];
        [edges release];
        edges = nil;
        if (newEdges)
        {
            edges = [NSMutableArray new];
            [self insertEdges:newEdges atIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [newEdges count])]];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this doesn't even achieve what I set out to do: by calling those KVO-compliant methods within a KVO-compliant method, I actually generate multiple notifications and the system turns out even less helpful than a standard accessor.

I settled on this verbose but effective method:

```
@synthesize edges;
- (void)setEdges:(NSArray *)newEdges
{
    if (newEdges != edges)
    {
        [self willRemoveEdgesAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0,[edges count])]];
        [self willInsertEdges:newEdges atIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0,[newEdges count])]];
        [edges release];
        edges = [newEdges mutableCopy];
    }
}

- (void)removeEdgesAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet*)indexSet
{
    [self willRemoveEdgesAtIndexes:indexSet];
    [edges removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexSet];
}

- (void)insertEdges:(NSArray*)newEdges atIndexes:(NSIndexSet*)indexSet
{
    [self willInsertEdges:newEdges atIndexes:indexSet];
    [edges insertObjects:newEdges atIndexes:indexSet];
}

- (void)willRemoveEdgesAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet*)indexSet
{
    //My side effects here
}

- (void)willInsertEdges:(NSArray*)newEdges atIndexes:(NSIndexSet*)indexSet
{
    //My side effects here
}
```

With some clever use of `respondsToSelector:` and `performSelector:`, you can even replace most of this code with a single-line preprocessor macro that automatically synthesizes all three accessors and calls your side effect methods iff you implemented them.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `edges = nil;` either after `[edges release];` or as the `else` clause. Otherwise passing a `nil` argument will make `edges` a dangling pointer to a released object.

Other than that, I don't see any issues with this implementation.

Answer (score 1):

[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:] leaks itself. it creates NSIndexPath object, and leaks by 16 bytes per call.

Comment: How do you come to this conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

It seems kind of bizarre.  You could just do:

```
- (void)setEdges:(NSArray *)newEdges
{
    if (newEdges != edges)
    {
        [edges release];
        [edges = [newEdges mutableCopy];
    }
}
```

Or if you want to keep some side effects.

```
- (void)setEdges:(NSArray *)newEdges
{
    if (newEdges != edges)
    {
        [self removeEdgesAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [edges count])]];
        [self insertEdges:newEdges 
                atIndexes:[NSIndexSet 
             indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [newEdges count])]];
    }
}
```

That saves an release/alloc pair.

Comment: Except that won't perform any side effects I may have in `remove<Key>AtIndexes:` and `insert<Key>:atIndexes:`--I'd have to repeat that code inside the accessor.

Comment: @andyvn22:  added an alternative.

Comment: What if `newEdges` is `nil`?

Comment: @andyvn22: ok, so you need a test for that eventuality.